# SSIS Aggregate- adding fields after an aggregate

Tags: ssis

I have two aggregates coming from a multicast and then into a merge join and then into a conditional split. The problem is I need to add additional fields after the conditional split so that both the additional fields and the results from the fields in the aggregates will also be in the flat file.  I tried doing a merge join from the multicast to the conditional split and it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add fields using the Derived Column transformation.

Comment: Thanks but will this get me the data that is in fields coming from the conditional split? If so what do I put in the derived column transformation?

Comment: If the Derived column is after the conditional split, then yes of course.  You put whatever you want in the derived column.   You haven't given any details about what the additional columns are, so I can't begin to guess what that would be.